# how to change format of floating point in hovertool display in bokeh

Tags: python, hover, bokeh, number-formatting

I am looking for syntax for float formatting for the '$x' in tooltips in hovertools in bokeh.
Using the following I can change the number of decimal places by using 0.0 or 0.00 after $x but documentation doesnt exist on how to do do math on the special variables $x , $y before displaying for example.

Searching for this I found an example that does something like this

```
 ht=HoverTool(
        tooltips=[
           ('x','$x{0}'), ],
        formatters={'$x':'printf',
        },)
```

can do printf formatting on x axis values in hovertool. The closest I found is using $x {0,0.0} which puts comma seperators in the number displayed according to help file from Bokeh. But I would like engineering format such as k, M, G suffix for larger numbers. Ideally the engineering_notation module could be paired with hovertool display values but not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [`NumeralTickFormatter`](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/formatters.html#numeraltickformatter). On the documentation page is a list with available options including examples.

**Minimal Example**

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_notebook, show
from bokeh.models import HoverTool, NumeralTickFormatter
output_notebook()

# create a new plot with the toolbar below
p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400, title=None)
x = [1e5, 0.5e6, 1e6]
y = [2, 5, 3]
p.circle(x, y, size=10)
ht=HoverTool(
        tooltips=[('x','$x{0.00 a}')],
        formatters={'$x':'numeral'},
)
p.add_tools(ht)
show(p)
```

**Output**
[image: Output]